# unable to use git echo commands in golang

Tags: bash, git, go, git-clone

I'm unable to echo a string into a new file , it works if I use a filename with some extension(.txt, .go, etc) but it doesn't work when I just use a filename without file extension

I want the below bash commands to be executed in golang

```
echo "testDir/*"> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout <Branch Name>
```

code snippet:

```
// Remove the redirect from command
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "testDir/*")

// Make test file
testFile, err := os.Create(".git/info/sparse-checkout")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer testFile.Close()

// Redirect the output here (this is the key part)
cmd.Stdout = testFile

err = cmd.Start(); if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
cmd.Wait()

branchCmd := exec.Command("git checkout <Branch Name>")
```

Comment: As mentioned it works when i don't use file name without extension, in my case i have to write to .git/info/sparse-checkout but it's not working. I'm not able to write into a file inside .git directory

Comment: Note that *Git* does not have an `echo` command; this is just a basic shell command. It's also not a good idea to redirect the entire `git checkout` output to `.git/info/sparse-checkout`. In Git terms you should use `git sparse-checkout` to manipulate the file (although direct file operations on the file will no doubt be supported for a long time).

Comment: yes, I'm doing git sparse-checkout before running the above two commands

Answer (score 0):

The echo command just print the list of arguments. The command interpreter (shell) expand the * based on globing existing filenames.

Without the shell, you can’t echo anything. You may need to call the shell (bash for instance) to expand and echo it, or use the `io` package to list files based on this pattern

Comment: Can you provide a sample code if you think it will work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly : in your bash command, `echo "testDir/*"` doesn't expand anything, it just outputs the string `"testDir/*"`. `echo ... > file` is just one of the gazillion ways to set the file content to a given value from your shell.

---

If you want to write a fixed string to a file in go, just write it :

```
_, err := testFile.Write([]byte("testDir/*\n"))
```

no need to start some external process to echo a value on stdout.